# URL subfolder rewrite without server access

Tags: redirects, url-rewriting, 404

I am having trouble with the following.

I have a site in development that has every link on the site pointing to the wrong folder.

Example:
`example.com/en/home/`, a site link goes to `example.com/en/`, which throws a 404.

Now the way the system is setup requires server access but I do not have that and information services is backlogged with requests and will take a week.

But I still need to develop the site. So is there a way to have the browser recognize when `example.com/en/` is clicked then automatically redirect it to `example.com/en/home` so it bypasses the 404 and I can actually work.

I'm looking for anything that gets the job done.

I am considering developing a Chrome app to do this but that would mean a ton of overtime and more work I don't want to do. Is there a easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just put a PHP/ASP/JSP or whatever server-side language you have available to you in the `/en/` directory with a redirect to `/en/home/`.

PHP Example:

```
<?php
    header('Location: /en/home/', true, 301);
```

If you can't do that much you're pretty much out of luck as all of the potential solutions are long-winded and PITA.